# Difference between opening a file and using a module

Tags: python

Below, I print out the `html` for a form defined externally. Is there a difference in the way each string is retrieved and used in `foo.py`, other than the syntax? If so, in what circumstances would one method be preferred over the other? For example, would I be better off defining a number of `html` files in a module as strings and access them that way, as opposed keeping them in separate .html files and using `open` over and over?

**mod.py**

```
form = """\
<form type="POST" action="test.py">
   Enter something:<input type="text" name="somethign">
</form>
"""
```

**form.html**

```
<form type="POST" action="test.py">
   Enter something:<input type="text" name="something">
</form>
```

**foo.py**

```
import mod

print mod.form

with open('form.html', 'r') as form:
   print form.read()
```

Comment: There is the slight overhead of opening and closing files; but it will only come into play if you are opening a very large number of files.

Comment: The Zen of Python: `import this`

Comment: OK, but is the `import` exactly == to a single file `open`? and are there any new processes being run when I access parts of the module that might be equivalent to opening a new file for example? I'm trying to establish the difference in mechanics between the two methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having .html files is better. Sure, you will have some overhead opening a file, reading its content and then closing it, but you'll have many advantages:

- .html file can be edited by any person who knows HTML syntax.
- .html files can be edited without restarting your program, it is very useful for services.
- You can eliminate open/read/close overhead by introducing some caching technique.

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot easier for designers to edit discrete HTML files than to deal with HTML embedded in code.